# Timer goes twice as fast when triggered again

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, timer

I need to make a system that puts in the integers into an array. But i have one problem. When I click the div it works, but when i click again the timer goes twice as fast. How can I prevent this problem?

code:

```
    // JavaScript Document
// DIT STUK ZORGT VOORT HET CLICK EVENT BIJ FUNCTION INIT
function addListener(element, type, expression, bubbling) {
    if(window.addEventListener) { // Voor alle !IE browsers
    element.addEventListener(type, expression, bubbling);
    return true;
    } else if(window.attachEvent) { // Voor oude IE versies
    element.attachEvent('on' + type, expression);
    return true;
    } else {
    return false; }
}

var mijnArray = [];
var Timer;

// Bij het laden van de pagina
function init ()
{
    addListener (document.getElementById("resultaat"), 'click', startTimer, false);
}

// Deze functie start wanneer er double geklikt is op de div
function startTimer ()
{
    //alert('test');
    Timer = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},100); 
}

function myTimer () 
{
    // uitvoeren zolang aantal items kleiner is als 11
    if (mijnArray.length < 10)
    {   
        mijnArray.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
        console.log(mijnArray);
        document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML = mijnArray;
    }
    else
    {
        clearInterval(Timer);   
    }

}
















window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Can you distill your code down to the smallest it can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the button, you're setting an interval. However, since the button is unaware of other intervals, when you click the button,you create a new timer, regardless of whether an old one is running or not!

Depending on which behavior you want exactly:

1. **Disable the button while the timer is running**: You can just remove the listener from the button when clicked until the timer is complete. (remove the listener in the end of startTimer and call init in the else clause of myTimer to re-enable the timer button).
2. **Make the button restart the timer**: Just run clearInterval on the Timer before enabling the timer again.

Answer (score 5):

Always assume your timer is running, cancel it before you start it

```
function startTimer() {
    clearInterval(Timer);
    Timer = setInterval(myTimer, 100); 
}
```

Alternatively, always leave the interval running, but have a flag which controls whether anything happens;

```
var do_something = false;

var Timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (do_something) myTimer(); // your function
}, 100);

function click_handler() {
    do_something = true;
}
```

---

As usual with intervals, you may want to consider the condition that the function invoked takes longer to complete than the interval waits before re-invoking it. If you have a situation like this consider re-writing it using `setTimeout`